# « Demande des heures » ou « demande d'heures » ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, articles

Dit-on « Demande des heures de vacation » ou « Demande d'heures de vacation » ?

---

Do we say “Demande des heures de vacation” or “Demande d'heures de vacation”?

Answer (score 2):

On dit « Demande **d'**heures de vacation ». Il s'agit ici d'un article indéfini contracté: **de des** -> **de** -> **d'** (comme: Une demande **de quelques** heures de vacation).

On dit en revanche « On demande **des** heures de vacation » (comme: on demande **quelques** heures de vacation).

Comment: Ce sont dans les deux cas le même article indéfini. La différence est que *des* disparaît après la préposition *de* par haplologie.

Answer (score 0):

> Il demande **des** heures de vacations pour terminer son projet.

... il a besoin d'effectuer plusieurs heures pour arriver à ses fins, demande *quantitative* précise.

> Il y a une demande **d**'heures de vacation pour le programme à venir.

... l'organisation a besoin de vacations pour pouvoir lancer son programme : demande *qualitative* non définie quantitativement.